# Non standard syntax; use & to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++, opencv

I keep getting this problem "Non standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"

---

I declared my function as:

```
public slots:
    void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* data_ptr);
```

---

And this is my function:

```
void MainWindow::mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* data_ptr) {
  MainWindow points;
  if (event == cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
  {
    userdata *data = ((userdata *)data_ptr);
    cv::circle(data->im, cv::Point(x, y), 2, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 5, CV_AA);
    cv::imshow("Camera Calibration", data->im);

    if (data->pts1.size() < 4)
    {
      data->pts1.push_back(cv::Point2f(x, y)); //x-6 ; y-5
      pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(x, y));
    }
  }
}
```

...................................................................

From my main function, I called this

```
//blabla
{
    //Do something here
    cv::setMouseCallback("Camera Calibration", mouseHandler, &data);

}
```

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Which line is the error on? You might consider a [mcve] so we can see the whole thing in context.

Comment: *use & to create a pointer to member* means what it says. Watch out, though. you may need a `static` method or free function there.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete details, the line "setMousecallback.." causes the error. It says 'MainWindow::mouseHandler': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member. Sorry but I am newbie in programming. Im trying to create a GUI for this code, its working in my VS2015 IDE but in qt creator, i receive this error

Comment: Please [edit] to add informatin. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to get your question lookin more like you intend it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As state by error message, you need `&` to take address of member method function:

```
cv::setMouseCallback("Camera Calibration", &MainWindow::mouseHandler, &data);
```

And as `cv::setMouseCallback` expects pointer on function, your method should be `static`.